# conditional parsing with antlr4 - skip the input

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a string to parse using antlr4 and I need to skip a token if a particular input is matched in a string.

For Example, a string contains number and string like below:

```
String = "87uuujdhhfj12ooiik56iijtg40jhdksa";
```

Parsing Output:

```
87 uuujdhhfj 
12 ooiik56iijtg   //here 56 is skipped
40 jhdksa
```

If string matches 12 while parsing then I need to skip next 12 (any value other than 12 is fine) characters from parsing.

Any reference or code to this type of parsing would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling this in the lexer will need a [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md#predicates-in-lexer-rules):

```antlr
lexer grammar TLexer;

@members {
  int charsToConsume = 0;
}

TOKEN
 : ( {charsToConsume-- > 0}? [a-zA-Z0-9] )+
 | [a-zA-Z]+
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+ {
     int n = Integer.parseInt(getText());
     if (n == 12) {
       this.charsToConsume = 12;
     }
   }
 ;
```

which you cab run with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "87uuujdhhfj12ooiik56iijtg40jhdksa";

    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    tokens.fill();

    for (Token t : tokens.getTokens()) {
      System.out.printf("%-15s '%s'\n", TLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()), t.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

and will print:

```
INT             '87'
TOKEN           'uuujdhhfj'
INT             '12'
TOKEN           'ooiik56iijtg'
INT             '40'
TOKEN           'jhdksa'
EOF             '<EOF>'
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks :)